# For how long coffee may stay in thermoses; meeting ECBC/SCAE/SCAA requirements, what does it mean?

Tags: brewing-process, flavor, equipment, storage, coffee-machines

We got in the office some kind of coffee-machine, I think it's *Moccamaster CD Thermo*, and it has 2 thermoses, to keep a coffee warm/fresh for certain period of time.

Thermoses are good and easy to use. I think they do great job in terms of electricity economy... But does it really good for a coffee quality? According to the specs, they say, it's keeping temperatures between 80°-85° and **meeting the requirements of the ECBC/SCAE/SCAA, what does it really mean**? It may be there are facts, which I haven't found, rather than too broad explanations, or opinion based thing.

I understand, that caffeine is not burning at temperature coffee is left at, and it does not evaporate. But **for how long it's acceptable to keep coffee in thermoses, without loosing the taste/smell and quality of coffee**?

Answer (score 1):

[ECBC](http://kaffe.no) , [SCAE](http://scae.com) and [SCAA](http://scaa.org) are organizations that are specialized in Coffee. They organize many events like contests. Sometimes these contests are held for people sometimes for equipment. They also produce many reports on Coffee; from taste of a cup to cultivation politics. So, these organizations also have a certification procedure for coffee brewing machines.

From the question, I understand that you want to keep the brewed filtered coffee in the carafe for a while and you are asking for the maximum allowed time for that.

The answer is; the machine will try to keep the coffee intact **as long as it can**; however, at that temperature the water will eventually vaporize and the rest of your coffee will turn into a bitter, dark, burnt coffee.

Simply, your coffee will eventually die as living beings and your high-quality gadget may just slow this, but cannot stop.

Solution: Just taste it. Fresh filtered coffee always tastes better. According to my experience, first half hour is the tasty period.

---

(1) European Coffee Brewing Center ([kaffe.no](http://kaffe.no))

(2) Specialty Coffee Association of Europe ([scae.com](http://scae.com))

(3) Specialty Coffee Association of America ([scaa.org](http://scaa.org))

Comment: Thank you! But it's not really what I asked. I haven't asked about coffee machine specifics, as well as we don't have carafe :). I was asking about thermoses (e.g. in our case it is *Moccamaster CD Thermo*) and keeping coffee in them, while temperature is stale for some period of time (no heating). I know what these abbreviations for associations mean, but the question was *... meeting the requirements of the ECBC/SCAE/SCAA, what does it really mean?*. It may be there are facts, rather than too broad explanation, or opinion based thing.

Comment: I meant the carafe of the brewing machine itself. :) I never heard that they have certified any thermos, sorry. Couldn't you find anything on the websites or in the manual? Some parts of the websites require membership, though...

Comment: neither me found... That's why asking :) But thank you for the try (I will up-vote for the effort)! My personal feeling is that it is another *marketing* thing, but wanted to find out some **facts** and **references**, rather that to rely on thoughts and a subjective opinion

Answer (score 1):

Well, I barely found any details and facts regarding keeping coffee in thermoses after brewing, and what does "*meeting the requirements of the [ECBC](http://kaffe.no/)/[SCAE](http://scae.com/)/[SCAA](http://scaa.org/)*" actually mean.

But while investigating and analyzing data, discovered interesting facts, to my mind, which are against of approach of keeping coffee in thermoses:

1. **Caffeine is getting out** quicker, than I was thinking. A cup of brewed coffee left at room temperature for [24 hours had about 60% of its caffeine remaining](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/r7ycf/does_dayold_coffee_lose_its_caffeine_content/). Coffee left at 4 degrees Celsius for 2 weeks had less than 5% of its original caffeine content.
2. It's **hard to wash** these kind of thermoses from inside, normally you just rinse them intensively. So initial bacteria concentrations are higher than in dish-washed containers and cups. (this topic on [cleaning of stainless coffee carafe](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1628/how-should-i-clean-a-stainless-coffee-carafe) could be considered)
3. **The coffee which gets into thermos containers isn't that boiling hot** (80°-85° according to specs) **to make the container "sterile"**. It would likely be safe for many bacteria that found coffee a nice growth medium. As the counter argument, for a sterile container, not related to thermoses storage: [coffee can be stored for and consumed within 8 weeks](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/66005) (the general bacterial count was <1 CFU/mL).
4. The thermos doesn't have heating source, and **loses it's temperature pretty quick** 1.5-3 hours, is my guess. It reaches ideal temperature (approximately 34-37 degrees) and boosts the processes being perfect medium, which encourages the growth of bacteria/fungi (*see #2 and #3 above*).
5. Coffee [degradation over time](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/123/when-does-coffee-go-off) and **the loss of aromatics affects the flavor profile**.

It may be there are other thoughts, links, references, facts to add here, welcome!

Comment: As far as I remember, there are some agents to clean coffee remains from thermos like media, which is hard to reach its interior. Yes, I found it. It's discussed [here](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1628/how-should-i-clean-a-stainless-coffee-carafe).

Comment: Thank you, @MTSan, I will add the reference to the answer

Comment: Another relevant answer is the second answer to http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34150/bottling-and-storing-cold-brewed-coffee - it references a [Korean scientific paper](http://www.dbpia.co.kr/Journal/ArticleDetail/NODE06070266) that analyzed cold-brewed coffee weekly for eight weeks.  The full paper is blurred unless you pay for it,  but squinting at Table 3 on page 4 I think the initial caffeine content of their brew was ~1200-1400 (not sure what units they were using) and after eight weeks this had declined to ~1000-1200, only a 15% loss. They did use a sterile container, though.