# What can I use to clean my machine as a substitute for original cleaners?

Tags: espresso-machine, cleaning, maintenance

I have access to an automatic bean-to-cup Siemens coffee maker. It has periodic cleaning programs of its own and also its own cleaning materials.

Recently, we have difficulties finding these cleaning materials around. (Sure we can order abroad, but this time customs, etc. probably will be a mess and it will take too much time and effort.)

Does anybody have an idea what can I replace these with?

Cleaner: [TZ80001](http://www.siemens-home.bsh-group.com/uk/supportdetail/product/TZ80001(01))
Descaler: [TZ80002](http://www.siemens-home.bsh-group.com/uk/supportdetail/product/TZ80002(00))

Answer (score 5):

In case you're still searching for alternative cleaning materials, I would recommend citric acid. You can easily find it pretty cheap on Amazon. Its the same concept as vinegar, but without the smell - vinegar will stink up your house and the machine, so I would recommend against it.

Comment: I almost exclusively use citric acid for descaling my machine.  It works great and is very cheap.  Definitely recommend over using vinegar.

Answer (score 4):

I have had multiple Breville products, and according to their recommendations, a good substitute is half white vinegar and half water. I've been using my current espresso machine for 2+ years, and this have only been following their recommendation. I find it works really well.

Answer (score 4):

After a while, I have managed to receive the products themselves. Therefore, it is better to mention what sits inside these products, directly reading from the packages.

The descaler is mostly citric acid as Evan noted. (I assume the percentages are by volume. Nothing noted, though.)

- 58±2 % citric acid
- 23±2 % maleic acid
- 23±2 % sulfamic acid

The grease cleaner is quite complex and its ingredients are noted without percentages. [See here](http://sumdat.net/0x2nwe9f). (This cleaner is said to be ideal for thermoses and flasks, too.)

- Sodium carbonate
- Sodium sulfate anhydrous
- Sodium percarbonate
- salt of phosphonic acid, organic
- Polyethylene glycol 8000
- Citric acid, anhydrous
- Potassium peroxomonosulfate

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure on the cleaning tablets, but I've heard Urnex Dezcal mentioned for a good descaler on multiple forums and it looks like a lot of people are using it for coffee machines based on Amazon reviews (and it has a very positive review rating).

Urnex also has a cleaning tablet for coffee makers which is probably the equivalent of what you are needing, although I would need more information about how you use the tablets to be sure.  I typically don't use detergents in my drip brewer, and use a Rocket branded cleaner for my espresso machine (came with the machine and I haven't run out yet).  Other options are a simple vinegar water mixture (I do 1/2 and 1/2, then 3 pots of pure water) and I've also heard you can use denture tablets to clean your coffee machine which might be worth looking into.