Breville espresso cleansing recommendations
Have you a Breville espresso machine?
I am 1) looking for a cheap alternative to the tablets online,

performs same function as the name brand tablets

I've researched the active ingredients, below

COMPOSITION/INFORMATION ON INGREDIENTS
Ingredients Name CAS Proportion
Sodium carbonate 497-19-8 30 - 60%
Sodium percarbonate 15630-89-4 10 - 25%
Ingredients determined not to be
hazardous
Blend Balance

Source: Cafetto

will simple baking soda (sodium carbonate) powder do the trick?

What is your experience?



You might want to see: https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/3756/what-can-i-use-to-clean-my-machine-as-a-substitute-for-original-cleaners
