# How to clean up brown black build up in a Moka pot?

Tags: moka, cleaning

Inside my Moka pot water chamber there is build up. It looks black/brown colour, as if coffee has been leaking into the water chamber, and then burning on. Or maybe just coffee oil.

Any tips on how to wash it? I did manage to scrape a little bit and it does seem to expose metal underneath. Any sort of soak would be nice.

[image: dirty moka pot water chamber]

Comment: What have you tried?  As daunting as this buildup looks, I've seen roughly similar patina on ill-used coffee mugs, and a wash with water has always impressed me with its surprising efficacy.  See this similar [Question and my Answer](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/1628/how-should-i-clean-a-stainless-coffee-carafe/1632#1632).

Comment: I have tried descaling by brewing white vinegar solution once. And soaking for like 5 minutes and rubbing. Will try a longer soak & rub.

Comment: Try some baking soda and warm water to soak.  The brown goop probably consisted largely of what are called tannic acids, and reacting with a mild base (the sodium bicarbonate) can produce organic salts that are more soluble in water (as a polar solvent).

Answer (score 2):

Soaking in vinegar seems to have helped the most.

[image: after vinegar]

Now it looks like something baking soda might work on. Or maybe will do vinegar again. Overall I am already happy with the result.